# What does MySQL Error 2013 mean?

Tags: mysql

I'm running mysqldump on a mysql server in a cron (as backup) and I'm getting warning messages like

```
mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when doing refresh
```

What does this MySQL error (2013) mean? I've done some googling and it's not very helpful...

For the record, mysqldump is connecting to a MySQL Slave server, it used to work when it was connecting to a master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be very bad, `2013` means that the thread servicing the `mysqldump` process has died. This could be because the InnoDB engine on the server has detected an error while reading the database file for you database. As `mysqldump` has to read all the pages for all of your database to make the backup it is likely to trigger any latent corruption that your application may avoid during it day to day activity.

If you run your `mysql` command and it reports that your connection id is a low number then you server has probably restarted itself. You should check your `mysqld.log` immediately to find out why.

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer, what did you find in your mysqld.log ?

Comment: I saw the low connection id which means the server restarted. I'm not sure why yet. How do I check for 'latent corruption

Comment: If your mysql sever has restarted itself there will be a large (read pages of debug) in the mysql log.

Answer (score 11):

2013 means that the connection to the server went away. There are several possibilities off hand:

1. Someone `KILL`ed the query
2. Network problems caused the connection to die
3. The server crashed/died
4. Your connection was idle for [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and was killed
5. The client wasn't pulling data fast enough for [`net_wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_write_timeout) and was killed

Comment: Is it **net_write_timeout** or **net_wait_timeout**?

Comment: also `net_read_timeout` =  **600** and `connect_timeout` = **60**

Answer (score 0):

do you open the connection, do a lengthy operation not involving the connection, and then attempt the query? if that is the case mysql probably dropped the connection due to the wait_timeout. simply re-connect before issuing the query.